# Accessing graphic object properties using dot notation on Matlab versions anterior to R2014b

Tags: matlab, syntax

Trying to change the colors of an Axis in a matlab plot here.

---

Referencing matlab documentation: [Matlab docs on setting axis properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html)

*Code snippet:*

```
    subplot( 'Position', [ left bottom (1/(cols*2)) (1/rows) ] );
    ax = gca;
    ax.Color = 'y';
```

That's all but a copy and paste from the example in the docs (shown here):

[image]

But matlab throws up a warning and doesn't change the axis colors for me:

> Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class
>   "double". See MATLAB R14SP2 Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure
>   Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details.

I tried assigning a double, like say 42.0, but it didn't like that any better.

Comment: I get the same error on my machine.

Comment: try `ax = handle(gca);` first, then `ax.Color = 'y';`

Comment: Are you using R2014b or an earlier release?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your warning message seems to indicate you are using a version anterior to Matlab R2014b.

If it is that, you do not have access to the dot notation directly because when you do `ax=gca;` you get a return value `ax` which is of class `double`. The value is the ID of the handle to the object *(the current axis in this case)* but **not** the handle itself.

When you try `ax.Color = 'y';`, Matlab thinks you want to overwrite your `ax [double]` with a new variable `ax` which would be a structure, with the field `color`, and throw a warning.

You can still access the dot notation for the graphic obects and properties but you have to first retrieve the real handle of the object, by using the function `handle`. For example:

```
ax = handle( gca) ; %// the value "ax" returned is an `object`, not a `double`
```

or even on an existing reference to a graphic object handle:

```
ax = gca ; %// retrieve the `double` reference to the handle
... 
ax = handle(ax) ; %// the value "ax" returned is an `object`, not a `double`
```

after that you should be able to use the dot notation for all the public properties of the graphic object. `ax.Color = 'y';` should now be valid

Comment: Nice answer! I didn't know about the `handle` function. Seems... handy :-P

Comment: Ah! r2014a, that's bizarre, I just installed this a few days ago, I assumed it was the latest and greatest.

Comment: @LuisMendo, quite handy in some case, and also faster if you have to refresh an object very frequently. If you like it, try `ax = java(handle(gca))`. it opens up a whole set of possibilities ... although undocumented.

Comment: @LuisMendo, more info (and as far as I can tell, all existent info) on the `handle` command can be found over at [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/performance-accessing-handle-properties). I [use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131998/continuous-plot-in-matlab/27132773#27132773) all the time.